# Wrong output when using if();{} in Java

Tags: java

What is the correction of this code? I can't get the right output, I want to sort alphabetically some strings. What is wrong with this program?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Alsort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,j,n;
        p("enter the value of n =");
        n=in.nextInt();
        String name[]=new String[8];
        String tname[]=new String[8];
        String tmp;
        p("enter the value or names");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            name[i]=in.nextLine();
            tname[i]=name[i];
        }
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            {
                if(name[i].compareToIgnoreCase(name[j])>0);
                {
                tmp=name[i];
                name[i]=name[j];
                name[j]=tmp;      
                }
            }
        }
        p("\n---------------------------------\n");
        p("Input Names\tSorted Names");
        p("\n-----------------------------------\n");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            p(tname[i]+"\t\t"+name[i]+"\n");
        }
    }

    static void p(Object anyObject){
        System.out.println(anyObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: What input are you providing, what is the output you expect, and what is the output you get? Add this information to your question by editing it, please.

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the last ";" from this line:

```
            if(name[i].compareToIgnoreCase(name[j])>0);
```

this is a very common error, basically the body of the if it's the ";" itself, i.e. the empty instruction, and the following block

```
            {
            tmp=name[i];
            name[i]=name[j];
            name[j]=tmp;      
            }
```

is always executed.
If you have an IDE with auto-format my advice is to use it extensively since it helps a lot to find this kind of errors, here how it looks after an auto-format:

```
    if (name[i].compareToIgnoreCase(name[j]) < 0)
      ;
    {
      tmp = name[i];
      name[i] = name[j];
      name[j] = tmp;
    }
```

as you can see it's very easy to spot the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problem in you code

1. The next int doesn't consumes whole line so you have do `nextLine()` after  `n=in.nextInt();` to consume the whole line.
2. Semicolon after `if(name[i].compareToIgnoreCase(name[j])>0);` which causes block after if to execute each time of loop.

   and also if both array `tname` `name` same names why not initialize them with length `n`

So the code would be

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System. in );
    int i, j, n;
    p("enter the value of n =");
    n = in .nextInt(); in .nextLine();
    String name[] = new String[n];
    String tname[] = new String[n];
    String tmp;
    p("enter the value or names");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        name[i] = in .nextLine();
        tname[i] = name[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (name[i].compareToIgnoreCase(name[j]) > 0) {
                tmp = name[i];
                name[i] = name[j];
                name[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    p("\n---------------------------------\n");
    p("Input Names\tSorted Names");
    p("\n-----------------------------------\n");

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tname));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        p(tname[i] + "\t\t" + name[i] + "\n");
    }

 }


 static void p(Object anyObject) {
    System.out.println(anyObject);
 }
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/gyKbXt)

Answer (score 0):

Easier to use `ArrayList` + `Collections.sort`, like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Dog");
list.add("House");
list.add("Cat");
list.add("Go");
list.add("Whoooo");
```

And then,

```
Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Which will give you a Sorted List.